# How to block google adsense ads in android webview?

Tags: java, android, webview

How to block google adsense ads in android webview?
I have an adsense enabled website and I am creating android webview app for that website. How to block adsense adss in that webview app? please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: follow this doc : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this: Set your custom user-agent to your webview and display "Show advertisements "," Hide advertisements " options on your fron-end based on google.com.ua/…
or 
Pass mobile_app=1 in URL When website open through webview, Then catch mobile_app=1 through GET method in website, Write code in website: if($_GET['mobile_app'] != 1) {// ads of Google}

Comment: How to pass mobile_app=1 in url and where I use the Get method. Please expllain

Comment: http://www.example.com/?

Consider this as your url 
then add one paramter to this url like this: http://www.example.com/?is_webview=1


Add your server side this code

if GET [is_webview] == 1
    store is_webview in session, or cookie
endif

if SESSION [is_webview] != 1
    echo ADSENSE_CODE
endif

Answer (score 0):

try to intercept and block the ads url using the callback shouldOverrideUrlLoading and shouldInterceptRequest .

Comment: How to do that? please help

Comment: public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.equals("ads url")) {

             return true ;
        }

      
     
    }

Comment: what will be the ads url?